# Expand DataFrame based on list and add index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

[image]

My goal is to expand the dataframe for each item in the list and add a index column that refers to position in the source list.

[image]

WHat is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode`:

```py
df = df.explode('Values')
df['index'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
```